# mt_rand() returns unexpected output

Tags: php, string, function, return

I am working with my ad system of my site and having trouble with this.

```
<?php

function bdads($size, $company) {
if($company == 'nufa') {
    if ($size == '300'){
        echo 'n300';
    }

    if ($size == '160'){
        echo 'n160';
    }
    if ($size == '728'){
        echo 'n728';
    }

    if ($size == '700'){
        echo 'n700';
    }
}

if($company == 'gnr') {
    if ($size == '300'){
        echo 'g300';
    }

    if ($size == '160'){
        echo 'g160';
    }

    if ($size == '728'){
        echo 'g728';
    }

    if ($size == '700'){
        echo 'g700';
    }
}

}

function bdad($size, $company){
$zsize = $size;
if($company == 'nufa'){
    echo bdads($zsize, 'nufa');
}
if($company == 'gnr'){
    echo bdads($zsize, 'gnr');
}
if($company == 'both'){
    $RandomList = [ bdads($zsize, 'gnr'),  bdads($zsize, 'nufa')];
    echo $RandomList[mt_rand(0, count($RandomList) - 1)];
}
}
?>
```

Now, Everything seems fine.. as example,

```
<?php echo bdad(728, 'gnr'); ?>
```

returning **g728** (as expected)

```
<?php echo bdad(300, 'nufa'); ?>
```

returning **n300** (as expected)

But all trouble is in generating random content.

```
<?php echo bdad(300, 'both'); ?>
```

returning **g300n300**
I want it to choose either g300 or n300 randomly.

**EDIT:**

- Changed `$a` to `$RandomList`, but still same result

Comment: Given the code provided, the both option would echo nothing at all.

Comment: You don't have a variable a -> `count($a)`  Where is it? Also you don't **return** your values

Comment: i think it is the problem.. $a shoud be $RandomList

Comment: @Sparrow No it's not returning any value

Comment: You're code [isn't very DRY either](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)...

Comment: @Machavity Your comment neither, you have 3 dots in it :)

Comment: For clarity of the site, please write an actionable question or request.  This will help the community hone in to what you need, and will make the question more searchable.

Comment: @Rizier123 True. I keep forgetting the unicode for ellipses :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to simplify your functions a bit:

You have to [**return**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) your values, otherwise your functions will return NULL by default. Also you can access a [string like an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), so I used `$company[0]` to get the first letter of the company, which you then can [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) with the size.

```
<?php

    function bdads($size, $company) {   
        return $company[0] . $size;
    }

    function bdad($size, $company){

        if($company == "both") {
            $RandomList = [bdads($size, "gnr"),  bdads($size, "nufa")];
            return $RandomList[mt_rand(0, count($RandomList) - 1)];
        } else {
            return dads($size, $company);
        }

    }

    echo bdad(300, "both");

?>
```

output:

```
n300 //Or g300
```

Comment: what is that `else` statement?

Comment: @Sparrow If you don't entered "both" You don't have to take a random one. So you just can call the function with the company name and the size

Comment: @Rizier123 then, maybe,`function bdad($size, $company = NULL) {`

Comment: And all I have to do .. add  `return $company[0] . $size;` at the end of `bdads` function, replace all `echo` with `return`, and I don't get that `else` part.

Comment: so.. I can delete `if($company == 'nufa'){
  echo bdads($zsize, 'nufa');
 }
 if($company == 'gnr'){
  echo bdads($zsize, 'gnr');
 }` and add `else {
            return dads($size, $company);
        }` at the bottom?

Comment: @Sparrow ^ The code in my answer is all you need. (I wrote an explanation what I changed/what the code now does)

Comment: @Sparrow A default value NULL wouldn't make any sense here

Comment: And another thing.. my first function have no deal with array. So, why I have to add `$company[0]` than just juing `$company`?

Comment: @Sparrow As I said in my answer, you can access a string like an array, so this will return the first letter of your company

Comment: Thanks Sir. I already solved my code with your answer and that g728, n160 etc are js code actually. I just replaced those js with those so that I dont have to post my site's ad code here... so, array is not needed.